# NoSuchMethodError in Tomcat embedded MULE when executing http:set-cookie

Tags: mule, mule-studio

When running Mule ESB 3.2.1 as embedded server inside Tomcat 7.0.27 (executed with webapp-runner), during execution of a flow with the Http endpoint, while sending response back to caller, an Exception is raised:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.ServerCookie.appendCookieValue(Ljava/lang/StringBuffer;ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;IZ)V
```

Exception Below:

```
org.mule.api.MuleRuntimeException: Connector that caused exception is: connector.http.mule.default

    at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector.handleWorkException(AbstractConnector.java:2034)

    at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector.workCompleted(AbstractConnector.java:1998)

    at org.mule.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:369)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.ServerCookie.appendCookieValue(Ljava/lang/StringBuffer;ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;IZ)V

    at org.mule.transport.http.CookieHelper.formatCookieForASetCookieHeader(CookieHelper.java:310)

    at org.mule.transport.http.transformers.MuleMessageToHttpResponse.createResponse(MuleMessageToHttpResponse.java:261)

    at org.mule.transport.http.transformers.MuleMessageToHttpResponse.transformMessage(MuleMessageToHttpResponse.java:90)

    at org.mule.transformer.AbstractMessageTransformer.transform(AbstractMessageTransformer.java:145)

    at org.mule.transformer.AbstractMessageTransformer.transform(AbstractMessageTransformer.java:93)

    at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.applyAllTransformers(DefaultMuleMessage.java:1387)

    at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.applyTransformers(DefaultMuleMessage.java:1348)

    at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.applyTransformers(DefaultMuleMessage.java:1331)

    at org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageReceiver.applyResponseTransformers(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:235)

    at org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageReceiver.routeMessage(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:214)

    at org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageReceiver.routeMessage(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:163)

    at org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageReceiver.routeMessage(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:150)

    at org.mule.transport.http.HttpMessageReceiver$HttpWorker.doRequest(HttpMessageReceiver.java:299)

    at org.mule.transport.http.HttpMessageReceiver$HttpWorker.processRequest(HttpMessageReceiver.java:258)

    at org.mule.transport.http.HttpMessageReceiver$HttpWorker.run(HttpMessageReceiver.java:163)

    at org.mule.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:310)
```

Comment: Mule 3.2.1 does not support `http:response-builder`. This feature has been introduced in 3.3.0. So, what version are you really using?

Comment: I am using Mule 3.2.1

Comment: Actually I am not able send the response back to caller.while sending back I am getting this exception.

Comment: I have version 3.7.0, but I also run into this problem. It only happens when http server has cookies in the response. And mule fails to parse the cookies. If the http server sends response without cookies, it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Mule 3.2.1, you can not use the `http:response-builder`. The feature is just not there. That's why you can't use it.

Check it out:

- It's not in the doc: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation-3.2/display/32X/HTTP+Transport+Reference
- It's not in the source: https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.2.1/transports/http/src/main/java/org/mule/transport/http/config/HttpNamespaceHandler.java#L56

Comment: I am not using http:response-builder.Can I use jetty in place of HTTP?

Comment: If you are running embedded in Tomcat, you should use **Servlet** inbound endpoints, not HTTP nor Jetty. You do not want to have Mule start another web container: instead you want to connect to the web container of Tomcat via the Servlet transport.

Comment: Tahnks..@David for your suggestion..Yes I am running running embedded in Tomcat.

Comment: In this particular flow I have used soap component..Is it a problem with **soap component**..?????because all other flow is working perfectly

Comment: SOAP components should work with the Servlet transport. If not, it's a bug that needs to be reported (unless it's been fixed, the version you are using is **very old**).

Comment: Can we use SOAP component with Http endpoint in ESB 3.2.1 version?? Please confirm it.

Comment: If by SOAP component you mean the CXF module, the answer is yes.

Comment: can you please suggest me why i am getting this exception then.

Comment: I am using HTTP Endpoint in two places 1. at start of the flow as a inbound-outbound 2. with cfx module

Comment: 1. Use a `servlet:inbound-endpoint`. 2. Keep using an `http:outbound-endpoint`.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. Check answer here.

[Mule ESB does not work with cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51964279/mule-esb-does-not-work-with-cookie)

In short, make sure you have provided group: 'org.apache.tomcat', name: 'coyote', version: '6.0.44' for mule 3.7.0.

In your case, you should have another library - **tomcat-util 5.5.23** because you use different version of mule **3.2.1**.

`compile group: 'tomcat', name: 'tomcat-util', version: '5.5.23'`

[image]

When you use SpringBoot, it ovverides a version of some library (depending on version of Spring and Mule), so you will get this error. You have class `ServerCookie` but the method `appendCookieValue` will disappear!

Solution - play with libraries. Or another **bad** workaround, write your own version of one of these classes that fail, and make sure classloader will use your version of the classes. (Again, creating a class with the same name and package to fix a bug - is a risky and bad thing...)